# How to remove Empty space above the chart

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highstock for displaying charts, but it is displaying unwanted empty space above the chart as shown in the image below.

Chart1:
[image: chart 1]
after disabling line chart(black), it was still showing empty spaces, as shown in the image below.

Chart2:
[image: chart 2]

but when I disable Thermal Chart it removes the empty space above the chart.

Chart3:
[image: chart 3]

my  question, how could i be able to remove unnecessary space in chart 1 and chart 2, like in chart 3

Comment: It's probably caused by `chart.alignTicks` option, which tries to match rounded numbers (ticks) on the axes. Set it to `false` and should be better. I suggest to read more about that option in the [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.alignTicks).

Comment: yes @PawełFus i know it is due to alighTicks, but if you have a look at figure 2, it does not make sense to add empty space above 2000, in figure 2, instead of disabling if I will remove line Chart, and draw again, it will not show empty space. The problem is it should not show empty space if line chart is disabled.

Comment: Recreate issue on jsFiddle, please. I will check this.

Comment: @PawełFus, I have recreated this issue on jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/73hoqk8p/9/ . plz try hiding or removing 'Outside_Temp' series, you will notice it is still showing unnecessary space after 800 kWh.

Comment: @PawełFus, In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7c9zx0bo/2/ , i have removed 'outside_Temp' series, now it is not showing unnecessary spaces above the chart. whereas if you will hide 'outside_Temp', instead of removing, it will keep showing empty space above the chart. i want that if we will hide the 'Outside_Temp', series, it should not show empty space above 800kWh, and i also want to keep using chart.alignTicks=true

Comment: Ok, but as you noticed, this is caused by `alignTicks`, that's how that option works. I really suggest to disable that option and use `tickPositioner`. See simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/73hoqk8p/10/

Comment: @PawełFus, your tickPositioner idea worked. please answer this question,  so that i may mark it answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to disable `alignTicks` option and use `tickPositioner`. Simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/73hoqk8p/10

Answer (score 0):

The unnecessary space in Chart 2 can be removed by setting [`chart.ignoreHiddenSeries`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.ignoreHiddenSeries) to `true` (it is `false` by default). [Here's the documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.ignoreHiddenSeries) for that option:

> If true, the axes will scale to the remaining visible series once one series is hidden. If false, hiding and showing a series will not affect the axes or the other series. For stacks, once one series within the stack is hidden, the rest of the stack will close in around it even if the axis is not affected. Defaults to true.